# MLE for uniform distribution with two parameters

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

A finite number of random variables $X_1 ... X_n$ have a uniform distribution $[a, b]$ with $b>a$, such that it has the following density:
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}, a\le x \le b$$
find the MLE.

Here's what I have tried:

$L(b,a;x) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i;b, a) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{b-a} = \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^n \\  
\mathbf{L}(b,a;x) = \log L(b,a;x) = -n\log(b-a)$

Taking the first and second derivative in respect to b, and then with respect to a.

$\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial b} = -\frac{n}{(b-a)} \\ 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial a} = \frac{n}{(b-a)} \\
\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial b^2} = \frac{2n}{(b-a)^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial a^2} = -\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial ba} = -\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}$

When I set the first two derivatves to zero to find the turning points, and these are when $b=a$.
To find the local maximum, I plug these into the hessian matrix:

$$H :=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial b^2}&\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial ba} \\ \frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial ba}&\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial a^2} \end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}&-\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2} \\ -\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}&-\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2} \end{pmatrix} \\ 
\\
= -\left(\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}\right)\left(\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}\right) -\left(\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}\right)\left(\frac{2n}{(b-a)^2}\right) =  -\frac{8n^2}{(b-a)^4}$$

Given that $\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{L}(b,a;x)}{\partial b^2}>0$ and $Det(H) < 0$, then our turning point is not a local maximum as the reverse inequality should happen for this to be the case.

However, this cannot be true. The actual question assumes three random variables such that $x_1 = 1.5, x_2 = 4.6, x_3 = 7.2$, and I'm supposed to plug these into the MLE. However, if there is no MLE then I cannot do this. So I have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: The values corresponding to maximum likelihood do not have to be where the derivative is zero; they could be at the extremes or where the likelihood is discontinuous or where its derivative does not exist

Comment: @Henry my book (Guide to mathematical methods - gilbert) mentions to find the values $x_1 .. x_n$ for which $f'(x) = 0$, however when I check again for those values $x_i$ for which $f''(x_i) < 0$ give a local maxima, if I plugin $b=a$ then I just get zero.

Comment: In your example, the likelihood of $b=a$ is $0$ since you should have $a \le 1.5 < 7.2 \le b$.  But your expression for the likelihood $\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^n$ suggests it should be infinite.  So perhaps your expression is missing something

Comment: @Henry I aimed to produce a general case but did not expect the results to not match what I had in mind. Instead, we would have $\prod_{i=1}^3 \left(\frac{1}{b-a} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^3$. Oh! would it be possible that I have to take the cdf first? $F_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^x dt = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ otherwise, the product then makes sense. Because we have $\prod_{i=1}^3f(x_i; b, a) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-a}{b-a} = \left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^n$?

Comment: In this particular example, the key point is that $a \le \min(x_i)$ and $b \ge \max(x_i)$ and so the likelihood of $a,b$ given $\{x_i\}$ is proportional to $\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^n I_{[a \le \min(x_i)]}I_{[b \ge \max(x_i)]}$ using indicator functions.  So the likelihood is no longer a continuous function of $a$ and $b$, with discontinuities at $a = \min(x_i)$ and $b=\max(x_i)$.  And that takes you back to my original comment.

Comment: @Henry Ah thanks for sharing this! it took me a while to remember continuous functions again and the use of your notations. So it's not a continuous function, meaning it does not strictly increase nor decrease. However, what do you mean by "derivative does not exist"? I'm still trying to piece some of your comments, could you perhaps write up an answer compiling the comments as a hint? Also is there a special term for the case $a \le x \le b$ when x is the infimum or supremum?

Comment: In another situation, if the likelihood was for example proportional to $e^{-|b-x|}$ then the maximum likelihood value for $b$ would be when $b=x$, even though the likelihood had no derivative with respect to $b$ there.  This situation is different and the issue is the discontinuities caused by the indicator functions.  Suppose  you saw your example data and you knew $a=0$.  Then you want to maximise $\frac1{b^3} I_{[b \ge 7.2]}$.  It might be worth sketching that for some values of $b$ above and below $7.2$ to see where the maximum is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a sample $X$, then $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is the MLE of $(a,b)$ where $X_{(k)}$ are the order statistics. Indeed the likelihood is
$$L((\theta_1,\theta_2),X)=\frac{1}{(\theta_2-\theta_1)^n}\prod_{k\leq n}\mathbf{1}_{[\theta_1,\theta_2]}(X_k)$$
which is maximized by $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$. To see this, note that $(\theta_2-\theta_1)^{-n}$ grows as $\theta_2-\theta_1\to 0^+$, but $L$ becomes $0$ as soon as the parameters 'pass' at least one of the observations $X_k$ (due to the product of the indicators).